# Laravel - how to properly override exception handling behavior?

Tags: php, laravel, exception, laravel-5.6, php-7.2

I've just read the [documentation about errors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/errors) in laravel 5.6 and I'm trying to override the behavior of 404 errors in my application. It is almost successful although not everything is working yet.

As the documentation states:

> [...] if you wish to customize the error page for 404 HTTP status codes, create a  resources/views/errors/404.blade.php. This file will be served on all 404 errors generated by your application.

So I did it and it worked fine... The problem is that the application calls the view without any custom variable and I want to pass an array to it with some data so I populate the HTML content. So what I did:

In the Exception Handler class, I added an IF for the case of Not found exception (404):

```
public function report(Exception $exception) {
    if($this->isHttpException($exception) && $exception->getStatusCode() == 404){
        return PagesController::return404();
    }
    parent::report($exception);
}
```

In the controller for this:

```
public static function return404()
{
    return view('errors.404')
    ->with('boards', BoardController::getAll());
}
```

But inside the view, the `isset` method is still returning false for the variable `$boards`. Assuming that the method `BoardController::getAll()` is correctly returning its value, what can be wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a view composer provider and send your variable from there like

```
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Controllers\BoardController;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ViewComposerProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer('errors::404', function($view)
        {
            $view->with([
                'boards' => BoardController::getAll()
            ]);
        });
    }


    public function register()
    {
    }
}
```

Check the details https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#view-composers